# Node-red installation fails on raspbian stretch with install script

Tags: installation, raspbian, node-red, stretch

I want to install node-red onto a fresh copy of raspbian stretch with the setup guide here: [Official install guide](https://nodered.org/docs/hardware/raspberrypi). I'm using the script that is mentioned on the website.

I started the script with the command: 
bash <(curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/node-red/raspbian-deb-package/master/resources/update-nodejs-and-nodered)

The questions I ansered are here:

Are you really sure you want to do this ? [y/N] ? y

Would you like to install the Pi-specific nodes ? [y/N] ? y

The install procedure hangs at the point "Install Node-RED Core".It just writes the line

> "Regenerating Makefile make: Warning: File [...]"

on and on. And here is the short extract from the /var/log/nodered-install.log

```
tar: lib/node_modules/npm/lib/init.js: time stamp 2017-12-21 19:06:09 is 1891263.546225 s in the future
tar: lib/node_modules/npm/lib: time stamp 2018-01-03 04:02:47 is 2960261.545225 s in the future
tar: lib/node_modules/npm/appveyor.yml: time stamp 2017-12-21 19:06:06 is 1891260.543714 s in the future
tar: lib/node_modules/npm: time stamp 2018-01-03 04:02:49 is 2960263.542535 s in the future
tar: lib/node_modules: time stamp 2018-01-03 04:01:10 is 2960164.541503 s in the future
tar: lib: time stamp 2018-01-03 04:01:10 is 2960164.540747 s in the future
tar: bin/npx: time stamp 2018-01-03 04:02:50 is 2960264.539403 s in the future
tar: bin/npm: time stamp 2018-01-03 04:02:50 is 2960264.53809 s in the future
tar: bin: time stamp 2018-01-03 04:02:50 is 2960264.537234 s in the future
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
npm WARN deprecated i18next-client@1.10.3: you can use npm install i18next from version 2.0.0
npm WARN deprecated nodemailer@1.11.0: All versions below 4.0.1 of Nodemailer are deprecated. See https://nodemailer.com/status/
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
/usr/bin/node-red -> /usr/lib/node_modules/node-red/red.js
/usr/bin/node-red-pi -> /usr/lib/node_modules/node-red/bin/node-red-pi

> bcrypt@1.0.3 install /usr/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v1.0.3/bcrypt_lib-v1.0.3-node-v57-linux-arm.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@1.0.3 and node@8.9.4 (node-v57 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
make: Entering directory '/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
make: Warning: File '../../../../../../../root/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/common.gypi' has modification time 2950515 s in the future
  ACTION Regenerating Makefile
make: Warning: File '../../../../../../../root/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/common.gypi' has modification time 2950511 s in the future
  ACTION Regenerating Makefile
make: Warning: File '../../../../../../../root/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/common.gypi' has modification time 2950505 s in the future
  ACTION Regenerating Makefile
make: Warning: File '../../../../../../../root/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/common.gypi' has modification time 2950501 s in the future
  ACTION Regenerating Makefile
make: Warning: File '../../../../../../../root/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/common.gypi' has modification time 2950497 s in the future
  ACTION Regenerating Makefile
make: Warning: File '../../../../../../../root/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/common.gypi' has modification time 2950493 s in the future
  ACTION Regenerating Makefile
make: Warning: File '../../../../../../../root/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/common.gypi' has modification time 2950489 s in the future
  ACTION Regenerating Makefile
make: Warning: File '../../../../../../../root/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/common.gypi' has modification time 2950486 s in the future
  ACTION Regenerating Makefile
make: Warning: File '../../../../../../../root/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/common.gypi' has modification time 2950482 s in the future
  ACTION Regenerating Makefile
make: Warning: File '../../../../../../../root/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/common.gypi' has modification time 2950478 s in the future
  ACTION Regenerating Makefile
make: Warning: File '../../../../../../../root/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/common.gypi' has modification time 2950474 s in the future
```

I even made a apt-get update & apt-get upgrade, but this doesn't help.

Is the install script broken? Is there a way around?

Best regards
Matt

Comment: Is the clock set correctly on your pi? All of those errors mention a file time in the future.

Comment: Dear knolleary, you were absolutely right. I adjusted the clock and it ran without a problem. Thanks for your kind help. Best regards Matt